# Shrink SonarQube database

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am running SonarQube 6.4 on Windows with a SQL Express database. The database has now reached the 10Gb limit of SQL Express and I would like to make it smaller.

I have remove some old projects and changed the 'Database Cleaner' settings but the database remains the same size (there isn't any free space in the files to shrink it).

Is there a way to force SonarQube to clean-up old/deleted projects?

Comment: Did you use the DBCC SHRINKDATABASE and/or DBCC SHRINKFILE operations?

Comment: Yes. The point is that the database isn't any smaller even though I have deleted data.

Answer (score 2):

Old analysises are automatically clean up after 5 years. Consider to lower that period in [`Administration > General > Database Cleaner`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Housekeeping).

Comment: I have dropped that value to 52, although we have only been using it for 6 months so that probably won't apply. I have deleted some projects that we no longer use but it still hasn't reduced the database size.